iCloud drive shows in Finder only files where I created a shared link
This is on MacOS Sequoia.
Until yesterday, I could see all my iCloud files from within Finder.
Today I messed this up in the following way: I wanted to do something on the command line with a certain file in iCloud drive. To avoid typing the complete path to the file, I clicked&dragged the file from Finder into my zsh command line in Terminal.app.
Usually, this results in the abs path of the file being pasted into the command line. This time however, nothing was pasted, and what Finder shows now under the "iCloud" location in the sidebar, was only a single directory named "Shared" (which I never created - perhaps a virtual folder maintained by Finder), and this directory contained only a single file (incidentally the only file on iCloud, where I recently created a public download link).
All other files from iCloud seemed to be gone. Fortunately I know the path of my iCloud drive when accessing it from the command line, and checking this path with ls -r, I saw that every file on iCloud was still in its place, just that only Finder did not show it anymore.
As a solution, I did a
ln -s '/Users/ronaldfischer/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs' ~/ICL

and now I have a symlink named ICL in my home, and when I open that ICL link in Finder,  I can again see my iCloud files.
This works, but I would prefer having Finder showing all of my iCloud files again, and most of all would like to know what exactly I did wrong. Click-dragging from Finder to Terminal worked so far without pro
 The screenshot shows how Finder shows iCloud right now. We see only the mysterious "Shared" folder on the sidebar, nothing else.

I won't be able to answer on how it happened without having the command you've typed, but here is how you can get back the "iCloud Drive" tab in the sidebar:

Open the Finder and go to Settings
Click on "Sidebar" and tick the iCloud Drive item

If using macOS Sonoma and earlier, you can also press ^⌘T while in the iCloud Drive folder to get it back in the sidebar (or ⌘T before Sonoma).


As for the "command", I didn't type any command yet at the time. I was clicking to the filename in finder, holding the mouse down, moving the mouse to Terminal.app and releasing the mouse. I planned to add the command in front of the pasted file afterwards. In short, the whole effect I encountered seems to have been caused just by click-dragging the file, so I guess I must have made a mistake during this operation.

I did have iCloud drive checked in my preferences, but your suggestions brought me to the idea of how to solve it. I will post my solution.

Here a solution, which is based on an idea of Lulucmy in his attempt to answer the problem:
When I opened my Finder preferences, I noticed that under the iCloud section, iCloud drive was checked, but Shared was unchecked. The preferences therefore look correctly. This was strange, because Finder behaved as if I had selected the preferences in exactly the opposite way: Finder was showing Shared, but not showing iCloud drive.
Anyway, I also put a checkmark into Shared, so that both entries have a checkmark, and now my iCloud drive is being displayed again.
The whole thing looks like a bug in MacOS to me: Something went wrong when click-dragging the file, and as a consequence the display in Finder was messed up. Modifying the preferences of Finder somehow seems to put things into a stable state. Perhaps simply unchecking iCloud drive and putting the checkmark back in would have helped as well.
